# release contents of UIWebView

Tags: iphone, memory-management, uiwebview

I have a ViewController and UIWebView created in Interface Builder in it. I fill webView with data like this:

```
 NSString *urlAddress = self.artUrl;

 //Create a URL object.
 NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlAddress];

 //URL Requst Object
 NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

 //Load the request in the UIWebView.
 [self.webView loadRequest:requestObj];
```

How should I release content of this webView in didReceiveMemoryWarning?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You either release the whole web view (if it is off-screen for example), or nothing at all. If you really need to release the contents, load a blank page.

Comment: Ok, thanks, the reason of this question is a memory loss, I created new question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3582908/uiwebview-and-huge-memory-loss can you advice anything? thanks